# Multi select listbox's last clicked item to textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to show the last clicked item on my ListBox that has multi-select. It only shows the first item on the list selected when I use the following:

```
Textbox1.text = listbox1.text
```

Comment: Do you actually mean the last item you selected, because you can also unselect a selected item with a click?

Comment: no I mean the last one I clicked on the list :)

Comment: In that case, you should be handling the `MouseClick` event, as selection is irrelevant. In that event handler, you can determine which item is at the mouse coordinates and display that item.

Comment: can you help me with the code??  im new at programming .. i really need some help

Comment: You haven't tried anything for yourself yet, so no. You've been pointed in a direction you were previously unaware of. Go in that direction and see what you can find.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option would be to store a list of the selected indices and add/remove to/from it whenever the selection changes.

Something like this should do the job (assuming WinForms):

```
Private selectedIndices As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Add the newly selected items.
    selectedIndices.AddRange(
        ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Cast(Of Integer).
                                 Where(Function(i) Not selectedIndices.Contains(i)))
    ' Remove the unselected items.
    selectedIndices.RemoveAll(Function(i) Not ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(i))

    ' Update the TextBox text. You can move this code to a different method
    ' if you want to trigger it using a button or something.
    If selectedIndices.Count = 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
    Else

        Dim lastIndex As Integer = selectedIndices.Last()
        TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(lastIndex))
    End If
End Sub
```

**See it in action:**

[image: Demo]

Comment: sir? Does this work with items from a binded data source??

Comment: Yes, it should work. What makes you think there's a difference?! Have you actually tried any of the suggestions that you received?

Comment: Yes Im trying every suggestions thanks for this...  It would help me a lot

Comment: it doesn't work ..it shows system.data.datarowview thats why I asked if this works for items that came from a binded source and not inputed manually

Comment: @JpDelos-SantosHortelano If the items in the ListBox aren't of type `String`, you can either cast the item to the original type and use the appropriate property or use `GetItemText()` to get the displayed text of a certain item. I've updated the answer above to show how you can use `GetItemText()` for that purpose.

Comment: I will try it immediately .. Thank you

Comment: one last question How do you get the selected items from that listbox so that I can use  it on my where statement on my SQL ... selected items wont work because it datarowview.. I've tried using                                                                                              Dim Studente As String = ListBox6.GetItemText(ListBox6.SelectedItems())
        UpdateLVe(Studente) but didn't do anything

Comment: @JpDelos-SantosHortelano That sounds like a good time to ask a new question. If you decided to do so, please make sure to include all the details and to provide a [repro].